# 32 bit SWT on 64 bit OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, swt, 32bit-64bit

I'm COMPLETELY new to SWT, but I ran into an error when trying to run my SWT package as a java application.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.swt.widgets.FirstSWTApplication.main(FirstSWTApplication.java:9)

The solution I found says to goto Eclipse prefs > Java > Installed JREs and edit the JRE's "Default VM arguments" with -d32.

This of course solves the issue when running "as java application" through eclipse.  Is it preferable to replace the 32bit libraries with 64 bit?  Or leave the -d32 default argument?  When I package and export this, will it run natively in OSX's 64bitenvironment?

Comment: OS X is largely 64 bit so I think switching to the 64 bit SWT is best. The Java 7 for OS X is only available in 64 bit so this is another reason to change.

Comment: Any idea where I can get this? The few links people have posted have turned up broken and it doesn't seem available from the same source the 32 but is.

Comment: Look on the [Eclipse 4.3 Platform downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3.1-201309111000/) site